# Creating html helpers without encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an html helper to render a button. As an example this needs to contain -

```
<button onClick="window.location='/Users/Edit/admin'">
```

I have tried to do this using TagBuilder but am having issues because MergeAttribute is encoding the html.

e.g.

buttonBuilder.MergeAttribute("onClick", "window.location='" + url.Action(action, controller, routeValues));

gives me -

```
<button onClick="window.location=&#39;/Users/Edit/admin">
```

Is there a way I can do this so it's not encoded? Or should I be using another method other than TagBuilder?

Comment: Solved, look to my new answer, i almost forget. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--EDITED

I almost forget, use the HtmlDecode:

```
public static class ButtonHelper
{
    public static IHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        TagBuilder button = new TagBuilder("button");
        button.MergeAttribute("onClick", "window.location='/Users/Edit/admin'");

        return new HtmlString(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(button.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Or look it: http://forums.asp.net/t/1377957.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks, the link you gave was very helpful, using buttonBuilder.MergeAttribute("onClick", "window.location=(" + new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(url.Action(action, controller, routeValues)) + ");"); worked for me :)

Comment: So, i will put in the answer again.

Comment: Well, if worked for you, you can mark as a answer and this answer may be helpful to another users. =)